# How to display date format in application according to region selected in iPhone setting(Language & Region)

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Below is the code I am using to show the date according to region selected. But is always shows the January 25, 2016. Not changing according to region change. E.g For U.S.: January 5, 2016 and U.K: 5 January 2016.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the date formatted based on the user's locale, don't set the locale. It will already default to the user's locale.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

BTW - your use of `NSLocaleIdentifier` isn't correct. That's some internal constant, not a value you would ever pass to `initWithLocaleIdentifier:`.